# How to update multiple grand child elements in Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I'm trying to update MongoDB grandchildren documents to update grand element values. For example, I need to update all the "ware" values to "LUX" where "ware" is "LAX".

In other words I need to change
"ware": "LAX", ---> "ware": "LUX",
However  "ware": "NYC", should not change

here is the example data.

```
[
{
"_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7b"),
"productCode": "aaaa",
"brand": "Nike",
"image": "some.jpg",
"sizes": [
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7e"),
    "size": "41",
    "wares": [
        {
        "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c80"),
        "ware": "LAX",
        "amount": 100
        },
        {
        "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7f"),
        "ware": "NYC",
        "amount": 7
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7c"),
    "size": "42",
    "wares": [
        {
        "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7d"),
        "ware": "LAX",
        "amount": 16
        }
    ]
    }
]
},
{
"_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7X"),
"productCode": "aaaa",
"brand": "Nike",
"image": "some.jpg",
"sizes": [
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7D"),
    "size": "41",
    "wares": [
        {
        "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c8G"),
        "ware": "LAX",
        "amount": 100
        },
        {
        "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7R"),
        "ware": "NYC",
        "amount": 7
        }
      ]
    },
    {
    "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7q"),
    "size": "42",
    "wares": [
        {
        "_id": ObjectId("5db72c636309f84479ec0c7n"),
        "ware": "LAX",
        "amount": 16
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I've tried this

```
db.getCollection('products').findAndModify({
query: { sizes: { $elemMatch: { wares:  {$elemMatch: { ware: "LAX" }}}}},
update: { $set: { "sizes.wares.$.ware": 'LUX' } }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.getCollection('products').updateMany(
   {},
   { $set: { "sizes.$[].wares.$[item].ware": 'LUX' } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ "item.ware": "LAX" }] }
)
```

Comment: This is not working :(
Got this message:
WriteError: No array filter found for identifier 'item' in path 'sizes.$[].wares.$[item].ware' :
WriteError({
 "index" : 0,
 "code" : 2,
 "errmsg" : "No array filter found for identifier 'item' in path 'sizes.$[].wares.$[item].ware'",
 "op" : {
  "q" : {
   
  },
  "u" : {
   "$set" : {
    "sizes.$[].wares.$[item].ware" : "LUX"
   }
  },
  "multi" : true,
  "upsert" : false
 }
})

Comment: The command is working (version 4.2), check your syntax and/or provide  **valid** sample documents. Your `ObjectId(...)` are not valid, for example.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with version 3.6.0

Comment: According documentation `updateMany` was introduced in 3.2, `arrayFilters` in 3.6 - so it should work

Comment: Actually it word on jmongoshel, but not in Robomongo :) So the problem solved, thanks!